# Problema com caracteres especiais em python

Tags: python, linux, windows, selenium-webdriver

Tenho um bot feito em Python com o **Selenium webdriver**, o qual pega alguns dados do [Tesouro Direto](https://github.com/bulfaitelo/Tesouro-Direto-Scraper) e gera um `json`, porem estou me deparando um problema, que ocorre quando um caractere especial aparece.

Para sanar esse problema adicionei o `.encode('utf8')` funciona perfeitamente, porem essa solução só é necessária no **Linux**, e quando uso o script em um sistema **Windows** com esse método ele gera um erro, porem sem esse `.encode('utf8')` o script no Windows funciona.

Erro no `Windows` com o uso do `.encode('utf8')`:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Erro no **Linux** sem o uso do `.encode('utf8')`:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 85-86: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Existe alguma forma de eu definir isso para que funcione nos dois sistemas ?

**tesouro_direto_protocolo.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# =========== IMPORTS =========== 
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta
from time import sleep
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
# ===============================


# ========== FUNCTIONS ==========
# Check if xpath existis
def is_element_present_xpath(xpath):
    try: firefox.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException: return False
    return True
# ===============================

print('[ {"inicio": "%s"},' % str(datetime.now()))
# necessario para funcionar remotamente
opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
firefox = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=opts)
# ============================================

# parametros
user_login = sys.argv[1]
user_pass = sys.argv[2]
try: 
    dir_file = sys.argv[3]
except:
    pass
default_file_name = 'erro.png'
wait_time = 10
# =====================================

# PAGINA DE LOGIN
firefox.get('https://tesourodireto.bmfbovespa.com.br/portalinvestidor/')
try:
    # preenchendo formulario de login
    login = WebDriverWait(firefox, wait_time).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'BodyContent_txtLogin'))) 
    password = WebDriverWait(firefox, wait_time).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'BodyContent_txtSenha'))) 
    login.send_keys("", user_login)
    password.send_keys("", user_pass)
    login_attempt = WebDriverWait(firefox, wait_time).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'BodyContent_btnLogar'))) 
    login_attempt.click()
    # ====================================

    # pagina de protocolos
    firefox.get('https://tesourodireto.bmfbovespa.com.br/portalinvestidor/consulta-protocolo.aspx')


    # INVESTIMENTOS
    # selecionando a operação
    select_operacao = Select(firefox.find_element_by_id('BodyContent_ddlOperacao'))
    select_operacao.select_by_visible_text('Investimento')

    # selecionando a data
    key_data_inicial = datetime.now()
    key_data_final = key_data_inicial - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    # data inicial
    data_inicial = firefox.find_element_by_id('BodyContent_dtRealizacaoInicial')
    data_inicial.send_keys("", key_data_final.strftime("%d%m%Y"))
    # data_inicial.send_keys("", key_data_final.strftime("17102017")) 
    # data final
    data_final = firefox.find_element_by_id('BodyContent_dtRealizacaoFinal')
    data_final.send_keys("", key_data_inicial.strftime("%d%m%Y"))
    # data_final.send_keys("", key_data_inicial.strftime("13062018"))  
    # clicando em consulta
    btn_consultar = firefox.find_element_by_id('BodyContent_btnConsultar')
    btn_consultar.click()

    # =====================================

    protocolos = firefox.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'responsive')]/tbody[2]/tr[contains(@class, 'nowrap')]")

    if is_element_present_xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'responsive')]/tbody[2]/tr[contains(@class, 'nowrap')][1]/td[2]"):    
        for protocolo in protocolos:
            numero_protocolo = protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]').text
            operacao = protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text
            situacao = protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[3]').text
            realizacao = datetime.strptime(protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]').text, '%d/%m/%Y')
            liquidacao = protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]').text
            if liquidacao:        
                liquidacao = datetime.strptime(liquidacao, '%d/%m/%Y')

            detalhes = protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[6]/img')
            detalhes.click()
            sleep(2)
            # modal detalhes 
            # modal_frame = firefox.switch_to.frame('modal')    
            detalhes_modal = firefox.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal"]')    
            # Dados Modal
            nome_representante = detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/label').text.split(' - ')
            nome_representante = nome_representante[0]
            titulo = detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]').text
            quantidade = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            valor_unitario = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            taxa_juros = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[4]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            taxa_b3 = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[5]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            taxa_custodia = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            valor_total = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[7]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            # print valores
            print('{ "numero_protocolo": "%s", "operacao": "%s", "situacao": "%s", "realizacao": "%s", "liquidacao": "%s", "representante": "%s", "titulo": "%s", "quantidade": "%s", "valor_unitario": "%s", "taxa_juros": "%s", "taxa_b3": "%s", "taxa_custodia": "%s", "valor_total": "%s" }, ' % (numero_protocolo, operacao, situacao, realizacao, liquidacao, nome_representante, titulo, quantidade, valor_unitario, taxa_juros, taxa_b3, taxa_custodia, valor_total)).encode('utf8')
            # fechando modal 
            sair_modal = detalhes_modal.find_element_by_class_name('close-reveal-modal')
            sair_modal.click()
    # INVESTIMENTOS -- FIM

    # RESGATE
    # Reiniciando a Consulta
    sleep(1)
    btn_consultar = firefox.find_element_by_id('BodyContent_btnConsultar')
    btn_consultar.click()
    # selecionando a operação
    select_operacao = Select(firefox.find_element_by_id('BodyContent_ddlOperacao'))
    select_operacao.select_by_visible_text('Resgate')

    # selecionando a data
    key_data_inicial = datetime.now()
    key_data_final = key_data_inicial - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    # data inicial
    data_inicial = firefox.find_element_by_id('BodyContent_dtRealizacaoInicial')
    data_inicial.send_keys("", key_data_final.strftime("%d%m%Y"))
    # data_inicial.send_keys("", key_data_final.strftime("17102017")) 
    # data final
    data_final = firefox.find_element_by_id('BodyContent_dtRealizacaoFinal')
    data_final.send_keys("", key_data_inicial.strftime("%d%m%Y"))
    # data_final.send_keys("", key_data_inicial.strftime("13062018"))  

    # clicando em consulta
    btn_consultar = firefox.find_element_by_id('BodyContent_btnConsultar')
    btn_consultar.click()

    # =====================================

    protocolos = firefox.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'responsive')]/tbody[2]/tr[contains(@class, 'nowrap')]")
    if is_element_present_xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'responsive')]/tbody[2]/tr[contains(@class, 'nowrap')][1]/td[2]"):    
        for protocolo in protocolos:
            numero_protocolo = protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]').text
            operacao = protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text
            situacao = protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[3]').text
            realizacao = datetime.strptime(protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]').text, '%d/%m/%Y')
            liquidacao = protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]').text
            if liquidacao:        
                liquidacao = datetime.strptime(liquidacao, '%d/%m/%Y')

            detalhes = protocolo.find_element_by_xpath('./td[6]/img')
            detalhes.click()
            sleep(2)
            # modal detalhes 
            # modal_frame = firefox.switch_to.frame('modal')    
            detalhes_modal = firefox.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal"]')    
            # Dados Modal
            nome_representante = detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/label').text.split(' - ')
            nome_representante = nome_representante[0]
            titulo = detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]').text
            quantidade = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            valor_unitario = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            taxa_juros = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[4]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            taxa_b3 = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[5]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            taxa_custodia = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            valor_total = (detalhes_modal.find_element_by_xpath('./div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[7]').text).replace('.', '').replace(',','.')
            # print valores
            print('{ "numero_protocolo": "%s", "operacao": "%s", "situacao": "%s", "realizacao": "%s", "liquidacao": "%s", "representante": "%s", "titulo": "%s", "quantidade": "%s", "valor_unitario": "%s", "taxa_juros": "%s", "taxa_b3": "%s", "taxa_custodia": "%s", "valor_total": "%s" }, ' % (numero_protocolo, operacao, situacao, realizacao, liquidacao, nome_representante, titulo, quantidade, valor_unitario, taxa_juros, taxa_b3, taxa_custodia, valor_total)).encode('utf8')
            # fechando modal 
            sair_modal = detalhes_modal.find_element_by_class_name('close-reveal-modal')
            sair_modal.click()
    # RESGATE -- FIM

    # Fechar navegador
    firefox.quit()
    print('{"fim": "%s"} ]' % str(datetime.now()))
except Exception:  
    if dir_file is not None:
        firefox.save_screenshot(dir_file + "\\" + default_file_name)
        pass
    firefox.quit()
    raise
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Python? Salvo engano, o `.encode('utf8')` só é utilizado no Python 2.

Comment: Realmente o python padrão do linux está o 2,7

Comment: Você deve estar usando Python2 no Linux e Python 3 no windows. Verifique isso.

Comment: Sim no linux o default está o 2.7 mas, esse problema ocorreria no Windows 2.7 também ?

Comment: No código que você enviou o encode está sendo chamado no retorno do print. Exemplo: print('texto').encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso aqui

```
op = "numero_protocolo" + numero_protocolo + "operacao" +  operacao + "situacao" +  situacao + "realizacao" +  realizacao + "liquidacao" +  liquidacao + "nome_representante" +  nome_representante + "titulo" +  titulo + "quantidade" +  quantidade + "valor_unitario" +  valor_unitario + "taxa_juros" +  taxa_juros + "taxa_b3" +  taxa_b3 + "taxa_custodia" +  taxa_custodia + "valor_total" +  valor_total
if op is not None:
     print(op.enconde("utf-8"))
```

**O que ocorre aqui?**

O valor que você tentou imprimir é NoneType (Sem valor) e não uma string, o erro é porque não existe `None.encode("UTF-8")`.

**Como isto é resolvido?**

Colocando um `if is not None`.
O codigo dentro do `if` só será executado se o valor não for `NoneType`